# How to get folder name from provided input path with CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the input path as C:\Student\Temp
 in the Temp folder, there will be many other folders. I want to get the latest folder name order by descending.

Comment: What do you mean by latest folder name - latest folder by creation or by usage ?

Comment: by folder name, all folders names are  with name as " created time"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir /b /a:d /o:d /t:c "C:\Student\Temp"') do set "latest=%%~nx#"
```

Comment: You should add the extension format (`set "latest=%%~nx#"`), for the case that some folder has no name and only extension.

Comment: How to print the folder name from the result, to verify the batch is working

Comment: @Gani `echo %latest%`